# what are the static and native methods of thread class

Tags: java

I faced the following question during an interview:

> What are the static and native methods of `Thread` class?
>
> 1. `yield`
> 2. `start`
> 3. `join`
> 4. `wait`

I know about multi threading concepts, e.g.:

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start(); // Thread starting execution
t.join(); // (or t.wait()) thread state will go to waiting
```

However I fail to answer the interview question mentioned at the beginning of the post.

Comment: I don't get why an interviewer would ask what methods are native. This is implementation dependent and a non native method could as well call a native one...

Comment: Interview questions that test your memory about specific apis or implementation details are poor tests of your knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Java Thread doc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Methods like `currentThread()` `sleep etc..`  ate `static` in nature.

There are few methods like `currentThread` `isAlive` etc are `native`.

Refer [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html).

```
yield -> public static native void
start -> public synchronized void start
join  -> public final synchronized void
wait  -> In object class
```

Comment: @amicngh sir, What is the meaning of native ? Could you please explain with example.

Comment: @SKR : Go through http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip23.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Javadoc for [`java.lang.Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). It essentially tells you that:

1. `yield()` is `static`
2. `wait()` is not `static`, and is inherited from `java.lang.Object`
3. `start` and `join` are not `static` and are defined by the `java.lang.Thread` class.

The `native`ness of these methods is very likely VM implementation-dependent, however it somewhat depends on what the question actually means by `native`.